# Ways to connect React-native App to IBM Watson Visual Recognition?

Tags: react-native, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, image-recognition, visual-recognition

I know there are ways to access IBM services to specific programming languages, but I have not seen anything in the docs about a way to connect my Watson Visual Recognition Service to React-Native.

glad if you can help me

Comment: There are Node.js SDKs for the IBM Watson services. React-native is based on JavaScript, right? There is also an API that can be called directly without the SDK. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try to explain better.  I have to create a native Application using React-native, which can take images and passes them to my IBM Watson Visual Recognition Service, to analyze and get an output.

Comment: which libraries I have to use?? thank you

Comment: Edit your question and make it more specific. Have you tried calling the API? Have you evaluated using the JavaScript /Node.js SDK? Any specifc programming issues?

Comment: Maybe you should start from here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-getting-started-tutorial

Documentation of the available APIs can be found here(V3 & V4):
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v3#introduction
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v4#introduction